# Microservice architecture but with strong data consistency

Tags: microservices, distributed-system, eventual-consistency

I'm working on a project that has microservice based architecture.

Recently we started facing problems where a single user requests requires updating multiple microservices each having it's own dedicated database and the response needs be sent to the user only after all the microservices have updates their databases.

I understand that there exists solutions like 2 phase commit, but it kind of seems like an anti-pattern and seems to have performance related issues and it would further complicate the system.

My question is whether it's even a valid ask of having strong data consistency in a microservice architecture? Or is it a bad design of service boundaries that we have to update multiple databases for a single user request.

I understand that this post doesn't include any low level exact details but wanted to know the opinion of community on this.

Edit:

Let's consider a social media platform where a user can add a post. By default that post is only shared with the people that follow the author. But the author of the post can optionally add few people and the post will be shared with those people as well.

As per our current design, post's data is stored in a separate microservice and data about who can see which posts is stored in a separate microservice. Both the data stores are relational.

Now, we want to have the ability for the post author to add other people while creating the post itself (instead of first creating the post and then adding people who can view that posts) and this should be an atomic operation. The problem with having this as an atomic operation is it requires updating two different microservice's datastore with no easy way to guarantee ACID constraints.

Comment: So you have an architecture made on purpose to work with eventual consistency and you have been asked to pervert it. Like making a fork to eat salads but also soups and why not do microsurgery now and then? Not gonna work. Not easily, if by easily we mean "magically". It's likely you will have to implement solutions you dislike, whether they "seem" antipatterns or not. Anyways. What's an antipattern if not a wrong solution for the wrong problem? Antipatterns are still solutions.

Comment: You don't have to go into *low level* details, but a little bit more details (with an example of what kind of data slices you are dealing with) could help to improve the question a lot.

Comment: @DocBrown Sure, will add more details in some time.

Comment: I think this could be a good question. I agree with Doc Brown about needing more info. Specifically, what constitutes a user request? An HTTP POST to a REST endpoint that fans out to multiple services, or does the client directly call the micro services?

Comment: @DocBrown Added an example, explaining the problem. Sorry for the delay, did not find time on week days.

Comment: @GregBurghardt There's a reverse proxy that directs the user request to the corresponding one or more microservices.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question. Thanks for the additional info.

Comment: @Laiv, Bart van Ingen Schenau, Please let me know if more details needs to be added to open the question.

Comment: I also voted to reopen.